# Trigger a cron with PHP

Tags: php, cron

I have users of a golf league program who are allowed to email their members. The average number of members is 40 but some leagues can have up to 150 members.

The email script uses phpmailer to send each member a personalized message and works well. I have a mail page that displays a sending gif while the script executes. Each email takes a little less than 1.5 seconds of browser time (on my connection) to execute so depending on the number of emails sent the browser could be tied up for several minutes.

What I would like to do is pass the execution to the server and release the browser back to the user so the user would not be staring at the loading image.

I could do this by storing mail data in the database and then having cron run every few minutes to execute the mail script but I wory about what problems would be caused by cron continuously running.

Is there a better way to do this? I do want to stay with PHPMailer

Comment: use `exec()`-type stuff to fire up a cli script that executes in the background, or fork the current PHP script into the background and do the mailing there.

Answer (score 0):

It is a nice approach. Just keep your script simple, tested and log any error. The worst scenario will be your script taking too much, so you can end with many scripts running at the same time.

Another approach is to write a daemon, here you can find a blog entry (with an update disclaimer) http://kvz.io/blog/2009/01/09/create-daemons-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

I'd deal with this by having the e-mails you need to send dumped into the database.

Have a cron run every so often and send xx e-mails.  If you are on a shared server you probably have limits on the amount of e-mails you can send per hour (even if they don't tell you).  Ask them, then plan accordingly.   You might only be able to send 100 e-mails an hour and actually have them go out for example.  Your script might try and send more, but they won't go!

Having a cron check for unsent e-mails every 5 or 10 minutes isn't going to be a performance issue.